# Can we reallocate same memory block which is freed earlier?

Tags: c

Is there any way to reallocate a freed memory block (which was allocated using `malloc` and freed using `free`) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard memory management routines (`malloc` *et al*) do not provide any way to request that a previously freed block be rereserved.

Comment: thanks for the answer...is there any workaround to achieve this?

Comment: @Jaat: Do not free the block you wish to keep. Another option would be to interpose the library routines with routines that retained freed blocks for a time and made them available. This is almost certainly not worth the work it requires to implement. Search for “interposition” for more information.